# Django3.0.1: after use ForeignKey then show this problem - This field cannot be null

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Django3.0.1: after use ForeignKey then show this problem - This field cannot be null.

I'm using Django 3.0.1 and MySQL database.

I've attached the code below - in models.py, views.py, forms.py

models.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug    = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import BlogPost
from .forms import BlogPostForm, BlogPostModelForm

# Create your views here.
# @login_required
@staff_member_required
def blog_post_create_view(request):
    # create objects - but how
    # ? use a form
    form = BlogPostModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user = request.user
        post.save()
        form = BlogPostModelForm()
    template_name = 'blog/create.html'
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import BlogPost


class BlogPostForm(forms.Form):
    title    = forms.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug     = forms.SlugField()
    content  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)


class BlogPostModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'content']

    def clean_title(self, *args, **kwargs):
        title = self.cleaned_data.get('title')
        post_title = BlogPost.objects.filter(title=title)
        if post_title.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This title has already been used. Please try again.")
        return
```

(terminal)migrations already done:

```
(venv)
fahim@Lenovo-IP320 MINGW64 /d/(G)/Python/try_django3.0
$ py manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
(venv)
fahim@Lenovo-IP320 MINGW64 /d/(G)/Python/try_django3.0
$ py manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
(venv)
fahim@Lenovo-IP320 MINGW64 /d/(G)/Python/try_django3.0
$
```

create.html:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Create New Post
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% if title %}
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endif %}

<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

the problem:
[This field cannot be null.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/corV5.png)

Comment: Could you add the code of your html template too?

Comment: Yes, I added Html code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`clean_<field>`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) methods should return the cleaned/validated value

```
def clean_title(self, *args, **kwargs):
    title = self.cleaned_data.get('title')
    post_title = BlogPost.objects.filter(title=title)
    if post_title.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("This title has already been used. Please try again.")
    return title
```

Comment: so what can I do?

Comment: Add `return title` to your `BlogPostModelForm.clean_title` method?